# 'Failed to encrypt sub-resource payload' error when attempting CI/CD

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We are trying to setup CI/deployment with DevOps using the documentation provided here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment. We are using a shared IR that has been set up in the target environment prior to deployment.

The release succeeds if the deployment mode setting is set to validation only, but fails when incremental or complete is selected. We get the following error when using override template parameters:

> 2018-09-21T17:07:43.2936188Z ##[error]BadRequest: {
>
> "error": {
>
> "code": "BadRequest",
>
> "message": "Failed to encrypt sub-resource payload

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your shared IR is online when doing the deployment, otherwise you may meet this problem because self-hosted IR will be used to encrypt your payload.

If you confirm the above action is done and you still have this error, please share the request activity ID to us and we can do some further investigation.

Comment: Where do we find the request activity ID in the release failure information? I have looked through the task logs and I am not finding anything.

Comment: just an fyi, the IR is definitely running and it is a shared IR we are referencing. we updated the arm template we have in dev to reference the IR in our integration environment for doing the release to make sure it references the right one. Just need to know how to get past this encryption issue. The connection already exists in our integration environment and we can't event get an incremental release to complete. validation release works just fine.

Comment: You may go to Azure portal -> resource group -> deployments -> select failed deployment name. In the popup window, you can see the deployment details and share the Correlation ID.

Comment: Thanks. The correlation Id is 122cd8b1-837b-4d73-879b-898db3f6f43e

Comment: We checked our backend log, we see there is an error "Invalid linked service payload, user Id and userName are both existed.". Please check your linked service payload whether you have user name both specified in "username" property and "connectionstring" property. We will also try to improve the error message to provide some more meaningful information.

Comment: We removed the user and pwd information from connection string and tried to run again and running into same error message. Here is the correlation id: Correlation ID:052450c6-6565-4731-adfb-489a7636b6fb

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've entered the right connection string into your parameters JSON for any linked services you are using. This fixed the error for me although I don't have a full CI/CD environment with IR established.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve it using the Azure Key Vault.

I added the connection string as a Secret.
In the connection string I also included the authentication data (username and password).

The limitation of this approach is that the possibility of passing the parameters is lost.
For example: dynamic values such as the name of the database or the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would request you to look into the connection string for the respective Linked Service for which you have attached IR. For my ASQL based Linked service I had to use something like this , simple server name would not suffice and you will get `"message": "Failed to encrypt sub-resource payload`

```
"typeProperties": {
            "connectionString": "Integrated Security=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;Data Source=axxx-xxx-xx-xxxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=\"@{split(linkedService().LS_ASQL_SERVERDB,';')[1]}\""
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I override parameter because of the connection string was secure. Use dummy value of(username, password, connection string) if You don't have original ones and then deploy.

Answer (score 0):

The IR already being running doesn't make sense when doing a full deployment of an ADF instance.  The IR key is generated within the instance of ADF you deploy, meaning you've created circular logic: you cannot deploy IR until the deployment of ADF is complete, but you can't complete the deployment of ADF until the IR is deployed.

So far our answer has been to let the arm template fail at this point, which is after the IR registration in the template so the IR key is then generated.  We use that to deploy the IR, then re-run the template and it succeeds... it's stupid and hacky and there has to be a more sane way to do this than intentional failure/retry.